# How can i create a floor map and add some markers in html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an image of the floor map over which i want add some **markers/pointers**.
I have added image in the canvas tag, but dont know how to create pointers.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a rectangle be on top of all other rectangles in javascript canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319628/how-can-i-make-a-rectangle-be-on-top-of-all-other-rectangles-in-javascript-canva)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to draw a circle at a certain co-ordinate of the canvas you can do the following:

```
// Draw a 10px circle at 100, 200
var x = 100;
var y = 200;
var radius = 10;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fill();
```

Comment: Thanx for such a quick reply. Will this circle be added over the image i have added in the canvas tag ?

Comment: @RahulMunjal it will be added on top of everything drawn before it, yes.

Comment: @RahulMunjal. Don't forget to checkmark this as an accepted answer if you found it to be so. That way this question comes off the "unanswered" queue of Stackoverflow. ;-)